# regulated function on $[0,1]$ such that $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$, $\int^1_0 f(x)dx=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Is there an example of a regulated function on $[0,1]$ such that $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$, $\int^1_0 f(x)dx=0$ and such that $f(x_0) \gt 0$ for at least one $x_0 \in [0,1]$?

[image]

I was thinking of $f(x)=0$ for $x \in [0,1)$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x=1$, but then it's not regulated, right?

Comment: The example you mentioned is a step function, so it is regulated.

Comment: @copper.hat but a regulated function is not supposed to be continuous? The one i mentioned is not continuous though, right?

Comment: @RobertIsrael okay, so is it possible for a function to satisfy the criteria above if it is not a step function though?

Comment: @Mavzouleus: No, but it is a regulated function. It depends on how you define a step function. Is the function $1_{ \{ { 1 \over 2  } \} }$ a step function?

Comment: @copper.hat well i'm not even sure what $1_{\frac{1}{2}}$ means to be honest

Comment: The function that is zero everywhere except one at $x={1 \over 2}$.

Comment: @copper.hat in this case yes, it is a step function.

Comment: Consider a function of the form $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty c_i 1_{\{r_i\}}(x)$ where $r_i$ are distinct members of $[0,1]$ and $c_i \to 0$ as $i \to \infty$.